# Sort On an .Include on Razor View Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, razor-pages

I've done basic sorts before and not had an issue, but this one has me stumped as to what I am doing wrong. All it returns is a blank page.

Details.cs (showing the sort code)

```
using RabiesClinics.Data;
using RabiesClinics.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace RabiesClinics.Pages.Pets;

[BindProperties]

public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public Pet Pet { get; set; }
    public Vaccine Vaccine { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Vaccine> VaxList { get; set; }

    public string VaxDateSort { get; set; }

    public DetailsModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int ownerid, string id, string sortOrder)
    {
        var ownerid1 = ownerid;

        Pet = _db.Pet.Include(pet => pet.Vaccines).FirstOrDefault(pet => pet.PetId == id);

        VaxDateSort = sortOrder == "VaxDate_Asc_Sort" ? "VaxDate_Desc_Sort" : "VaxDate_Asc_Sort";

        IQueryable<Model.Vaccine> vaccine = from s in _db.Vaccine select s;

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "VaxDate_Asc_Sort":
                vaccine = vaccine.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated.ToString());
                break;
            case "VaxDate_Desc_Sort":
                vaccine = vaccine.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateVaccinated.ToString());
                break;
            default:
                vaccine = vaccine.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated.ToString());
                break;
        }
        Vaccine = await vaccine.ToListAsync();

        if (Pet is null)
            return new NotFoundResult();
        else
            return Page();
    }

}
```

Pet Details view where the sort occurs (shortened for space):

```
@page
@using RabiesClinics.Model
@model RabiesClinics.Pages.Pets.DetailsModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="border p-3 mt-4">
        <div class="row pb-2">
            <h2 class="text-primary pl-3">Pet Details <img src="~/Images/PawPrints.png" /></h2>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <table class="table table-borderless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Pet.OwnerId"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Pet.OwnerId" name="ownerid" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Pet.PetId"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Pet.PetId" name="id" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Pet.PetName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Pet.PetName" type="text" disabled class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Pet.LastVaxDate"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Pet.LastVaxDate" type="text" disabled class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%">
                    <div class="form-group, mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Pet.Status"></label>
                        <br />
                        @foreach (var item1 in Html.GetEnumSelectList<Status>())
                        {
                            <input type="radio" disabled asp-for="Pet.Status" value="@item1.Text" />
                        @item1.Text
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <h4>Vaccines</h4>
        <br />
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Tag No
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-sortOrder="@Model.VaxDateSort">Date Vaxxed</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Print Rabies Certificate
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Pet.Vaccines.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 10%">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <input asp-for="Pet.Vaccines[i].RabiesTagNo" type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 10%">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <input asp-for="Pet.Vaccines[i].DateVaccinated"  type="date" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="10%">
                            <div class="w-75 btn-group" role="group">
                                <!--Line below is good.-->
                                <a asp-page="/RabiesCertificates/Details" class="btn btn-primary mx-2" asp-route-id="@Model.Pet.PetId" asp-route-vaxdate="@Model.Pet.Vaccines[i].DateVaccinated">
                                    <i class="bi bi-printer"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
        </table>
        <div>
            <a asp-page="/Owners/Details" asp-route-ownerid="ownerid1" asp-route-id="@Model.Pet.OwnerId"  class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 250px;">Back to Owner Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>
}
```

If someone could point out where I have gone astray, I would much appreciate it! I have learned a lot from this forum so far that I have been able to apply on multiple apps!

ADDED: Update based on suggestion

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int ownerid, string id, string sortOrder, DateTime vax)
    {
        var ownerid1 = ownerid;

        Pet = _db.Pet.Include(pet => pet.Vaccines).FirstOrDefault(pet => pet.PetId == id);

        VaxDateSort = sortOrder == "VaxDate_Asc_Sort" ? "VaxDate_Desc_Sort" : "VaxDate_Asc_Sort";

        IQueryable<Model.Vaccine> vaccine = from s in _db.Vaccine select s;

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "VaxDate_Asc_Sort":
                vaccine = vax.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated);
                break;
            case "VaxDate_Desc_Sort":
                vaccine = vax.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateVaccinated);
                break;
            default:
                vaccine = vax.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated);
                break;
        }
        VaxList = await vax.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Why are you using ToString() in the OrderBy.  A DateTime will sort without ToString().  The string is probably not going to give the correct order.

Comment: I have just been trying multiple things to get this to work. That was one of them. If I remove the .ToString(), I get this error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<RabiesClinics.Model.Vaccine>' to 'RabiesClinics.Model.Vaccine'

Comment: You are getting back a generic list and cannot convert to a singleton RabiesClinics.Model.Vaccine.  Create a new variable for the results of OrderBy instead of reusing vaccine.

Comment: "All it returns is a blank page." By blank do you mean no result or the whole HTML page is blank? Can you check the result source code (right click browser, View Source)?

Comment: @LukeVo It returns an entire blank page. Clicking on View Page Source opens another tab in the browser with an equally blank page.

Comment: @jdweng, I updated code (see post above), but it still does the same thing. I think I am misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: @MelB in that case, it's not even because of the wrong query. You need to check why no HTML is being printed. Can you check the result HTML page source (right click in browser, View Page source) and determine why it's printed that way?

Comment: You need two variables 1) vaccine for the IQueryable 2) vax for the OrderBy.   The results of the OrderBy is not the same format as IQueryable.

Comment: @jdweng. Please see update above. Is this what you mean? I still get errors. error CS1061: 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' , 'OrderByDescending' and 'ToListAsync'

Comment: Should be : IQueryable<Model.Vaccine> vax = from s in _db.Vaccine select s;   I think you are getting error due to vax being null.

Comment: @jdweng If I make that one change, I get this error: error CS0103: The name 'vaccine' does not exist in the current context. I'm getting very confused. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start off with a few QoL improvements.

You used 14 lines to describe sorting:

```
VaxDateSort = sortOrder == "VaxDate_Asc_Sort" ? "VaxDate_Desc_Sort" : "VaxDate_Asc_Sort";

IQueryable<Model.Vaccine> vaccine = from s in _db.Vaccine select s;

switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "VaxDate_Asc_Sort":
        vaccine = vaccine.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated.ToString());
        break;
    case "VaxDate_Desc_Sort":
        vaccine = vaccine.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateVaccinated.ToString());
        break;
    default:
        vaccine = vaccine.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated.ToString());
        break;
}
Vaccine = await vaccine.ToListAsync();
```

There's something to be said for keeping it like this if you expect multiple sorting methods to be added in the future. However, the devil is in the details:

```
VaxDateSort = sortOrder == "VaxDate_Asc_Sort" ? "VaxDate_Desc_Sort" : "VaxDate_Asc_Sort";
```

Why are you making the `VaxDateSort` the opposite of `sortOrder`? Why even have a seperate property if you don't mutate it afterwards?

Since `VaxDateSort` is implied to always have a value, you can add the `default` switch statement to another case, like:

```
default:
case "VaxDate_Asc_Sort":
    vaccine = vaccine.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated.ToString());
    break;
```

Now, you already had some help with fixing some of your other mistakes, so putting it all together with your improved version and fixing the last mistakes you made (`vax` was the datetime parameter of your method, not the db list), this should let your code compile at least.

I recommend taking a close look at the official MS documentation example of what you're trying to do and cross-referencing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

```
using RabiesClinics.Data;
using RabiesClinics.Model;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace RabiesClinics.Pages.Pets;

[BindProperties]    
public class DetailsModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public Pet Pet { get; set; }
    public Vaccine Vaccine { get; set; }
    public IList<Vaccine> VaxList { get; set; }

    public string VaxDateSort { get; set; }

    public DetailsModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int ownerid, string id, string sortOrder, DateTime vaxDate)
    {    
        //TODO: inccorporate ownerid and vaxDate as filters
        SelectedPet = _db.Pet
            .Include(pet => pet.Vaccines)
            .FirstOrDefault(pet => pet.PetId == id);

        var vaccines = from s in _db.Vaccine select s;

        if (sortOrder == "VaxDate_Desc_Sort")
            VaxList = await vaccines.OrderByDescending(a => a.DateVaccinated).ToListAsync();
        else
            VaxList = await vaccines.OrderBy(a => a.DateVaccinated).ToListAsync();
                    
        if (Pet is null)
            return new NotFoundResult();
        else
            //TODO: HTML view does not use the Model.Vaccine or Model.VaxList
            return Page();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not a programmer. I am following what I have learned in video tutorials. This was the way I learned to do sorting. Honestly, I only need it to be a fixed ascending sort. I could not figure out how to do that, so I went back to what I had learned hoping that would work. It did not. I will happily read the link you gave me. However, as I have no formal training and have been doing this less than a year, I do not understand much of what any MS documentation says. It is way over my head. That's why I have leaned on Youtube tutorials so much.

Comment: @MelB in this case I linked to a literal example tutorial. Copy/paste the code. Change the labels and then modify in very small steps from there.

What you're doing now is very much trying to run before you can walk. 

Either you copy someone else's work and live with a few basic adjustments, or you need to sit down and learn the basics and create it from scratch just the way you want and need. Doing a mix of both you'll end up with an unmaintainable piece of junk that you can't edit or keep working in 3 years time.

Comment: thank you. I appreciate your thoughts and agree completely. I am doing the "copy someone else's work and make basic adjustments" as much as possible and learning a lot along the way. It has always been trial by fire here. At this point, I do not have time to sit down and completely learn all of this. So, I survive on my early 1990s HTML/VB skills. I will likely be retired within a year. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Code should look like this

```
        IQueryable<Model.Vaccine> vaccine = from s in _db.Vaccine select s;
        var vax = null;
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "VaxDate_Asc_Sort":
                vax = vaccine.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated);
                break;
            case "VaxDate_Desc_Sort":
                vax = vaccine.OrderByDescending(s => s.DateVaccinated);
                break;
            default:
                vax = vaccine.OrderBy(s => s.DateVaccinated);
                break;
        }
        VaxList = await vax.ToListAsync();
```